# Why does my regex break inside a Makefile?

Tags: c, regex, bash, makefile

I have a bunch of C source files named sequentially (say `f1.c`, `f2.c`, `f3.c` etc).

In my Makefile I have a `clean:` definition which used to look like this:

```sh
rm -f f1
rm -rf f1.dSYM
rm -f f2
rm -rf f2.dSYM
# etc
```

So I wanted to replace that with a regex, and this works great if I input it directly into the command line:

```sh
ls | grep -P ^f[0-9]+(|\.dSYM)$ | xargs rm -rf
```

However, if I then put that command in my clean definition, when I run `make clean`, I get this:

```sh
$ make clean
ls | grep -P ^f[0-9]+(|\.dSYM)| xargs rm -rf
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ls | grep -P ^ex[0-9]+(|\.dSYM)| xargs rm -rf'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I guess there are some special characters in my regex that are causing a syntax error... I've tried quoting and escaping stuff but nothing's really helping, does anyone know how I could get this working inside my Makefile?

Comment: That pipe in your regular expression looks like it's breaking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another solution, using `$(wildcard)` to find the C sources and pattern substitution to get the derived file names:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard f[0-9]*.c)

clean :
    rm -f $(SOURCES:.c=)
    rm -rf $(SOURCES:.c=.dSYM)
```

Comment: that's really neat.. first solution on here that works for every case, thanks!

Comment: you'll need to manually delete generated files if you remove source files while the build directory is 'dirty'; that's rarely an issues, though...

Answer (score 4):

```
ls | grep
```

is a useless use of `ls`. http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

```
rm -rf f[0-9] f[0-9]*[0-9] f[0-9]*.dSYM
```

In clear, use **globing**. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob.

Comment: that doesn't delete the binaries for me, just the .dSYM

Comment: Can you provide a real full example of what you want to delete ?

Comment: say I make `f1.c`, `f2.c` and `f3.c`. I get binaries for each e.g. `fn` (no extension) and a `fn.dSYM` directory for each. I want to delete all the binaries and the .dSYM directories, but not the C source files

Comment: nearly there.. can you use `+` with globbing? I need it to work for 2 or more digits as well.. thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Not the `+` character in globs. You can use `f[0-9]*[0-9]` to match any number length. I will edit my post with that,.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12081/discussion-between-sputnick-and-alex-coplan)

Answer (score 1):

Direct solution: quote your regex. Better solution: globs, brace expansion, and/or `find ... -delete`.

```
rm -rf f{1,2}{,.dSYM}
rm -rf f? f?.dSYM
ffind . -regex '.*/f[0-9]' -o -regex '.*/f[0-9].dSYM' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line shell is probably different from the shell `make` uses. I guess you use `/bin/bash` at the command line, but make uses `/bin/sh` by default. You can change it by prepending

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to the Makefile.

Adding quotes around vertical bars and parentheses is always safer than use them unquoted. Also note that the dollar sign must be doubled in a Makefile not to be treated as a special character.